# Spark DataFrame filter not working as expected with Random

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

This is my DataFrame

```
df.groupBy($"label").count.show
+-----+---------+                                                               
|label|    count|
+-----+---------+
|  0.0|400000000|
|  1.0| 10000000|
+-----+---------+
```

I am trying to subsample the records with label == 0.0 with the following:

```
val r = scala.util.Random
val df2 = df.filter($"label" === 1.0 || r.nextDouble > 0.5) // keep 50% of 0.0
```

My output looks like this:

```
df2.groupBy($"label").count.show
+-----+--------+                                                                
|label|   count|
+-----+--------+
|  1.0|10000000|
+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.nextDouble` is a constant in the expression so the actual evaluation is quite different from what you mean. Depending on the actual sampled value it is either

```
scala> r.setSeed(0)

scala> $"label" === 1.0 || r.nextDouble > 0.5
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((label = 1.0) OR true)
```

or

```
scala> r.setSeed(4096)

scala> $"label" === 1.0 || r.nextDouble > 0.5
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((label = 1.0) OR false)
```

so after simplification it is just:

```
true
```

(keeping all the records) or

```
label = 1.0
```

(keeping only ones, the case you observed) respectively.

To generate random numbers you should use [corresponding SQL function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@rand():org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand

scala> $"label" === 1.0 || rand > 0.5
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((label = 1.0) OR (rand(3801516599083917286) > 0.5))
```

though Spark already provides stratified sampling tools:

```
df.stat.sampleBy(
  "label",  // column
  Map(0.0 -> 0.5, 1.0 -> 1.0),  // fractions
  42 // seed 
)
```